# XCode 5.1 Could not build module darwin

Tags: ios

My app runs perfectly on ios 7.1 but when i try to run it on the 7.0 devices it gives me this "Could not build module darwin" error. i have also tried changing the architectures to use armv7 and armv7s but still to no avail. Please i need help with this

Comment: Go to log navigator and paste here the details of the error.

Comment: This is actually a decent question. Blame XCode defaults. I had to change the architecture on build settings to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your build settings, take a look at these two settings:

- `Base SDK` (in the Architecture section) - make sure this is set to 7.0 or earlier.  I think it defaults to "Latest" which would be 7.1.
- `iOS Deployment target` (in the Deployment section) - make sure this is 7.0 or earlier